# Getting the weird hexadecimal code on the top of the page of the sitemap

Tags: php, xml, sitemap, phalcon

I have been struggling with this weird issue. I have created the sitemap of a website. The sitemap is dynamic and has a huge set of URLs.

The problem I'm facing is that google is not accepting it. On deeply investigating I found out that there is some kind of weird hexadecimal code before the 'https://prnt.sc/qkdbhc'

You won't be able to see it while visiting the sitemap link or even viewing the source code. I was able to detect it using the 'https://websniffer.cc/'

I debugged in every way to check if that is coming from my code, but no use. Putting this question here, maybe someone encountered this problem and solved it.

Immediate help would be appreciated.

Comment: Was the sitemap created by hand in a code editor? Or automatically generated by a script?

Comment: What is the size of the sitemap you're trying to upload? That is, could 0x17bd (or 0xbd17) be that filesize? How did you build the sitemap, in code or with an editor?

Comment: @MartinBean I have generated the sitemap by a script

Comment: @droopsnoot The sitemap is in chunks, each sitemap file size is around 100 kb to 1 mb max

Comment: Might be a BOM (Byte Order Mark)

Comment: @ZeeshanFaiz, if it's generated by a script, perhaps you could post the code to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@ZeeshanFaiz

I'm the creator of the [WebSniffer](https://websniffer.cc) tool that you used to test your sitemap. I'm terribly sorry, but this hexadecimal code is **a bug** of our sniffer script, which is known and will be fixed soon. It has nothing to do with your sitemap.

I tested your sitemap with the xml-sitemaps site and your sitemap [seems to be valid](https://www.xml-sitemaps.com/validate-xml-sitemap.html?op=validate-xml-sitemap&go=1&sitemapurl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.finduslocal.com%2Fsitemap.xml&submit=Validate%20Sitemap). There is also a [Sitemaps testing tool](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/sitemap-list) within the Google Search Console. I highly recommend to use it to figure out if and what kind of complains does Google have in regard to your sitemap.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi. Thank you for taking the time and responding to this question. :-)